# Publicly available (rdf) color ontology?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

Is there any publicly available (rdf) color ontology?
Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the resources of **dbpedia**.

SPARQL:

```
select distinct ?c where {?c a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour> }
```

[http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3Fc+where+{%3Fc+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FColour%3E+}&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?c%20where%20%7B?c%20a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour%3E%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on)

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Turquoise_(color)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Orange_(colour)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gold_(color)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Terracotta
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cobalt_blue
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Orchid_(color)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Buff_(colour)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Isabelline_(colour)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Egyptian_blue
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Phthalocyanine_Green_G
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Phthalocyanine_Blue_BN
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Vermilion
(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Linked Open Colors](http://linkedopencolors.appspot.com/) vocabulary, which provides IRIs for all colours of the RGB spectrum.

**Edit:** as Joshua Taylor said in comments, the link was dead so I changed it. I also added a sentence to say what the link is about, to address the "this is a link only answer".

**Edit (bis):** The link is now dead for good. Ignore this answer and feel free to downvote it many times. However, [the code is still available](https://bitbucket.org/moreways/loc) and theoretically could be redeployed elsewhere in the future, thus I keep the answer here.

Comment: This is a link only answer, and the link is dead.

Comment: The link is dead again, couldn't find a working one.

Comment: Seems to live at https://github.com/timrdf/vsr/wiki/Linked-Open-Colors now. I think it was originally a joke since RGB triples are their own unique identifiers, meaning a URI is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've just published a colour ontology (open source, open license, etc.). Don't use it just yet, it really needs some feedback and to be used in anger (which I will do soon). It's the first ontology I've published, so it's very possible there are noob problems in it.

But I think it's almost usable, so please have a look and contribute/comment here if you like. The repo is linked from the site. I'll edit this post when it's ready for use.

https://www.cyannotation.org/

Parenthetically, the closest thing I found to a 'semantic' colour space in my research is the [ISCC–NBS system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCC%E2%80%93NBS_system). I'm (reasonably) confident that could also be described using the ontology above, so that's a task for someone in the future;) I'd be happy to publish the individuals from that system too.